# Given a set (universal set) $Ω = \{1,2,3,4\}$, is its power set, a Dynkin system, an algebra and a π-system?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

A [Dynkin system][1], is a collection of subsets of another universal set ${\displaystyle \Omega }$ satisfying a set of axioms weaker than those of σ-algebra.

here is one of the Definitions that wiki gives

> Let Ω be a nonempty set, and let ${\displaystyle D}$ be a collection
>   of subsets of Ω. Then D is a Dynkin system if
>
> 1. Ω ∈ D
> 2. if A ∈ D, then $A^c$ ∈ D
> 3. if $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ is a sequence of subsets in D such that $A_i ∩
>     A_j$ = Ø, for all i ≠ j, then  ${\displaystyle \bigcup _{n=1}^{\infty
>     }A_{n}\in D} $

Given a set (universal set) $Ω = \{1,2,3,4\}$, is its power set D,

\begin{equation*}\left\{\emptyset, \left\{1\right\}, \left\{2\right\}, \left\{3\right\}, \left\{4\right\}, \left\{1, 2\right\}, \left\{1, 3\right\}, \left\{1, 4\right\}, \left\{2, 3\right\}, \left\{2, 4\right\}, \left\{3, 4\right\}, \left\{1, 2, 3\right\}, \left\{1, 2, 4\right\}, \left\{1, 3, 4\right\}, \left\{2, 3, 4\right\}, \left\{1, 2, 3, 4\right\}\right\}\end{equation*}

a Dynkin system, an algebra and a π-system?

Comment: It is a $\sigma-$algebra, so is a Dynkin system, an algebra and a $\pi-$system.

Comment: @FengShao Thank you! Please mv the comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a $\sigma-$algebra, so is a Dynkin system, an algebra and a $\pi-$system. In fact, the power set of any set is a $\sigma-$algebra, as you must have already konwn.